# Why is str_replace() only replacing one instance of a character in a string?

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a large string variable that is assigned from a database column of type "**Text"** with Collation latin_swedish_ci.

Because it is in ASCII, I need to replace all non UTF-8 characters before I can put variable into my PDF generation script.

As we all know, the standards used by PDF are evil. If I use plain ASCII input it will go insane and cause a rip in space-time.

So in order to prevent anymore damage to our universe, I need help figuring out why this `str_replace()` function is only replacing one of a character type and ignoring any  repeats of this character

**Here is my code:**

```
$tc = str_replace (array("\n", "£", "&"), array("<br/>", "&pound;", "&amp;"), $tc);
```

**Input:**

```
Terms & Conditions: Mandatory charge of £10 for cancellations.    
VAT E&EO
```

**Output:**

```
Terms &amp; Conditions: Mandatory charge of &pound;10 for cancellations.
VAT E&EO
```

As you can see in the output on the second line the `str_replace()` does not change the ampersand character.

I wonder if this is because its over two lines or something like that.

So any idea how to get the function to work as I want it to, otherwise well your going to wake up with many Micro Blackholes vanishing your bowl of cereal tomorrow.

Comment: As mentioned, there are built in functions to handle html entities. But that aside, `strtr` is the function that makes the most sense for this type of string substitution.

Comment: [Unable to reproduce this problem](http://ideone.com/qhVG9h).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you are trying to achieve could be done using these 2 functions:

```
nl2br(htmlentities($tc));
```

The benefit being that if your `$tc` variables gets any more HTML entities in the future, you won't have to fiddle with your `str_replace()`.

Comment: I concur. Perfect solution. I'd prefer to use these and code a replace only when there are no alternatives.

Comment: I've never come accross this function. Somehow I feel my life is going to become a lot less stressfull now! :)